# A limit formula for the Schwarzian derivative involvng cross-ratios

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove a formula involving limits and the Schwarzian derivative.

> Let $U$ be a domain and $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a nonc-constant
> holomorphic function. The $\textit{Schwarzian derivative}$ $S(f)=\frac{f^{'''}}{f'}-\frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{f^{''}}{f'} \right)^2$ measures
> infinitesimal small changes of the cross-ratio. Let $z_1,z_2,z_3z_4
> \in \mathbb{C}$ be pairwise distinct, and assume that $0 \in U$ with
> $f'(0) \neq 0$. Then we have
>
> $$ \lim_{t \to 0}
> \frac{\text{cr}(f(tz_1),f(tz_2),f(tz_3),f(tz_4))-\text{cr}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)}{t^2 \text{cr}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)}=\frac{(z_1-z_3) (z_2-z_4)}{6} S(f)(0) $$

I started as follows. We define

$$ 
\lambda_1=\text{cr}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)
$$

and

$$
\lambda_2=\text{cr}(f(tz_1),f(tz_2),f(tz_3),f(tz_4)).
$$

Since $f$ is holomorphic it has a power series expansion around $0$

$$
f(z)=a_0+a_1 z+a_2 z^2+a_3 z^3+O(z^4), \ \text{where} \ a_n=\frac{f^{(n)(0)}}{n!}. 
$$

Then using the definition of the Schwarzian derivative I get

$$
S(f)(0)=\frac{6(a_1a_3-a^2_2)}{a_1^2}
$$

and

$$
\frac{S(f)(0)}{6}=\frac{(a_1a_3-a^2_2)}{a_1^2}. \tag{*}
$$

Using the series expansion I get

$$
\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{t^2 \lambda_1}
=\frac{1}{t^2} \frac{z_2-z_3}{z_1-z_2} \frac{z_4-z_1}{z_3-z_4}
\left( \frac{a_0+a_1 (tz_1)+a_2 (tz_1)^2+a_3 (tz_1)^3+O((tz_1)^4)-
(a_0+a_1 (tz_2)+a_2 (tz_2)^2+a_3 (tz_2)^3+O((tz_2)^4))}
{a_0+a_1 (tz_2)+a_2 (tz_2)^2+a_3 (tz_2)^3+O(tz_2)^4)
-(a_0+a_1 (tz_3)+a_2 (tz_3)^2+a_3 (tz_3)^3+O(tz_3)^4))}
\frac{a_0+a_1 (tz_3)+a_2 (tz_3)^2+a_3 (tz_3)^3+O((tz_3)^4)
-(a_0+a_1 (tz_4)+a_2 (tz_4)^2+a_3 (tz_4)^3+O(tz_4)^4)}
{(a_0+a_1 (tz_4)+a_2 (tz_4)^2+a_3 (tz_4)^3+O((tz_4)^4))
-a_0+a_1 (t z_1)+a_2 (tz_1)^2+a_3 (tz_1)^3+O((tz_1)^4}
-\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_2-z_3} \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_4-z_1} \right)
=\frac{1}{t^2} \frac{z_2-z_3}{z_1-z_2} \frac{z_4-z_1}{z_3-z_4} \\
\left( \frac{a_1 t(z_1-z_2)+a_2 t^2 (z^2_1-z^2_2)+a_3 t^3 (z^3_1-z^3_2)+O((tz_1)^2)-O((tz_2)^2)}
{a_1 t(z_2-z_3)+a_2 t^2 (z^2_2-z^2_3)+a_3 t^3 (z^3_2-z^3_3)+O((tz_2)^2)-O((tz_3)^2)}
\frac{a_1 t(z_3-z_4)+a_2 t^2 (z^2_3-z^2_4)+a_3 t^3 (z^3_3-z^3_4)+O((tz_3)^2)-O((tz_4)^2)}
{a_1 t(z_4-z_1)+a_2 t^2 (z^2_4-z^2_1)+a_3 t^3 (z^3_4-z^3_1)+O((tz_4)^2)-O((tz_1)^2)}
-\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_2-z_3} \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_4-z_1} \right)
$$

Now I want to get something like  $\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{6} S(f)(0)+O(t)$. Is there an efficient way to simplify the expression above?

Comment: See the nice article : http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~ovsienko/Publis/what-is.pdf

Comment: Surely you meant to write the limit as $t$ goes to $0$ instead of $\infty$?